# How to mount gluster volume to host folder in docker?

Tags: docker, glusterfs

I have ran my docker container like this:

```
docker run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup -v /opt/doc:/opt/doc \
--privileged=true --net=host -itd --name=gluster gluster-docker
```

then I mount a volume to a folder in container:

```
mount -t glusterfs 192.168.1.100:/documents /opt/doc
```

When I write data to the /opt/doc of my real server, the data won't be rsync to the /opt/doc of the container.

Is there any idea to rsync data between container and server after I have mounted the folder ?

gluster-docker: https://github.com/gluster/gluster-containers

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found *--mount* in docker-ce 17.06.

```
mount --bind /data/fff /data/fff
mount --make-shared /data/fff
docker run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup -v /opt/doc:/opt/doc \
--privileged=true --net=host --mount \
type=bind,source=/data/fff,target=/data/fff,bind-propagation=rshared \
-itd --name=gluster gluster-docker
```

then I mount a volume to the folder in container:

```
mount -t glusterfs 192.168.1.100:/documents /data/fff
```

OK.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt